# can a type member which is a type be a target?

Tags: fortran90

Suppose I have the following setup

```
 type BarType
     integer :: i
 end type

 type FooType
    type(BarType) :: bar
 end type
```

I want to have another type

```
type BazType
   type(BarType), pointer :: barPtr
end type
```

and set `barPtr` to point to `foo%bar`. To do this I would have to declare `type(BarType), target :: bar`, but I got an error. I didn't investigate further, and decided to change strategy, but just for curiosity, do you know if this is allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the standard, but the way I read it, a derived-type component can not have the `target` attribute; if you want to associate a pointer with such a component, you have to declare the parent object as `target`.